# How to iterate for lazy compilation

Tags: ruby

**How in Ruby do I ...**

- iterate over two folders (paths given as an initial constant or paths taken from a json file)
- and compare their time stamps, triggering a certain command (an empty foo()-function for now, just printing the filename) on the former, if it's timestamp is same-or-old than the latter.

I want to build a lazy aka lean update mechanism, much like `make` in the old days, which only re-compiled C files, if they are newer.

*[ And that, just to let you know, I want to do, to bypass some heavy corporate JEE deployment mechanism, where in fact only one or two css/jsp files keep changing (as frontend designers do) and need to be pushed from dev to server root. :-]*

**Forgive me the scope of the question, I am a complete noob to file operations in ruby...** but it seems the best available cross-plattform scripting in my environment at hand.

Comment: Tree walking is available via tutorials and examples on SO and across the internet. This has nothing to do with lazy evaluation, btw.

Comment: Ever thought of using `rake`?

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(bar)
   puts bar
end

def bar(first,second)
   puts "#{first} is not older than #{second}"
end

def compare_time_stamps

    Dir.foreach("path/one") do |filename|
        @first_file << File.ctime(filename)
    end

    Dir.foreach("path/two") do |filename|
        @second_file << File.ctime(filename)
    end

    @first_file.zip(@second_file)
    @first_file.each do |first_time,second_time|
        @first_time.parse_time >= @second_time.parse_time ? foo(@first_time) : bar(@first_time,@second_time)
    end


end
```

edit--
Which time stamps are you trying to compare @Fronker? Are you trying to compare file1 of folder 1 with file1 of folder 2 or file1 of folder 1 with file 2 of folder 1

This is not tested, but with some editing it should work. You will need to make a method -- perhaps using regex -- to parse the 'ctime' method into a time stamp format that you want. This is really rough and i'm not for sure if it will even work like it is supposed to so take it lightly with a grain of salt. When I get home I will edit it to be better but for now this should get you started with which methods might work.
Hopfully this helps somewhat, Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a build system written in Ruby, called `rake` (stems from Ruby Make) that already has an implementation of detecting changed task dependencies and only running a chain of tasks that are affected.

You might find [this introduction to rake](http://martinfowler.com/articles/rake.html) useful.